# I don't have property name in my table but I am getting invalid column name error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have an IssueActivity model and I have an IssueActivityDetail model of this model, and I made it self-parent so that this can be the detail of IssueActivityDetail. But I am getting this error even though I do not have an IssueActivityId1 column.

```
public partial class IssueActivitiy
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IssueId { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public short SubActivityNo { get; set; }
        public string SubActivityTitle { get; set; }

        public virtual Issue Issue { get; set; }
        public virtual List<IssueActivitiyDetail> IssueActivitiyDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public partial class IssueActivitiyDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IssueActivitiyId { get; set; }
        public string LineNo { get; set; }
        public string Definition { get; set; }
        public byte RoleId { get; set; }
        public string Medium { get; set; }
        public string Explanation { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }


        public virtual IssueActivitiy IssueActivitiy { get; set; }

        public virtual List<IssueActivitiyDetail> IssueActivitiyDetails { get; set; }
        
        public virtual IssueActivitiyDetail Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

My FLuentApiConfiguration IssueActivitiy at ef core

```
modelBuilder.HasOne(d => d.Issue)
                .WithMany(p => p.IssueActivitiys)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IssueId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("FK_Issue_IssueActivitiy_Id");

            modelBuilder.HasMany(z => z.IssueActivitiyDetails)
               .WithOne()
               .HasForeignKey(z=> z.IssueActivitiyId);
```

My FLuentApiConfiguration IssueActivitiyDetailat ef core

```
 modelBuilder
                .HasMany(z => z.IssueActivitiyDetails)
                .WithOne(z => z.Parent)
                .HasForeignKey(z => z.ParentId);
```

Comment: Which version of efcore you are using?

Comment: I am using 5.0 in ef core

Comment: By the way, there are only two `i`s in Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My try:
I use this kind of DbContext:

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IssueActivitiy> IssueActivities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IssueActivitiyDetail> IssueActivitiyDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase())
            .LogTo(s => Debug.WriteLine(s));

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IssueActivitiyDetail>()
            .HasMany(d => d.IssueActivitiyDetails)
            .WithOne(p => p.Parent);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

This are the data model classes I would use:

```
public class Issue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class IssueActivitiy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public short SubActivityNo { get; set; }
    public string SubActivityTitle { get; set; }

    public Issue Issue { get; set; }
    public List<IssueActivitiyDetail> IssueActivitiyDetails { get; set; }
}

public class IssueActivitiyDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LineNo { get; set; }
    public string Definition { get; set; }
    public byte RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Medium { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }


    public IssueActivitiy IssueActivitiy { get; set; }
    public List<IssueActivitiyDetail> IssueActivitiyDetails { get; set; }
    public IssueActivitiyDetail Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my resulting migration:

```
public partial class Initial : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Issues",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Issues", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "IssueActivities",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Type = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                SubActivityNo = table.Column<short>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                SubActivityTitle = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                IssueId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_IssueActivities", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_IssueActivities_Issues_IssueId",
                    column: x => x.IssueId,
                    principalTable: "Issues",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "IssueActivitiyDetails",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                LineNo = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                Definition = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                RoleId = table.Column<byte>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                Medium = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                Explanation = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                IssueActivitiyId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                ParentId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_IssueActivitiyDetails", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_IssueActivitiyDetails_IssueActivities_IssueActivitiyId",
                    column: x => x.IssueActivitiyId,
                    principalTable: "IssueActivities",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_IssueActivitiyDetails_IssueActivitiyDetails_ParentId",
                    column: x => x.ParentId,
                    principalTable: "IssueActivitiyDetails",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_IssueActivities_IssueId",
            table: "IssueActivities",
            column: "IssueId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_IssueActivitiyDetails_IssueActivitiyId",
            table: "IssueActivitiyDetails",
            column: "IssueActivitiyId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_IssueActivitiyDetails_ParentId",
            table: "IssueActivitiyDetails",
            column: "ParentId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "IssueActivitiyDetails");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "IssueActivities");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Issues");
    }
}
```

So maybe simplicity wins here, as efcore5 will do lots of stuff for us.
So I'm not sure if the resulting database structure fits your expectations, but it works/compiles so far.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, your answer solved my problem. Putting a restriction on FluentApi was enough to solve my problem.